# How to print a string for flagged nodes?

Tags: theming, flags

I have a flag called "Mark as SOLD" which can be flagged only by node author. When he flags it as "Sold", I want the node teaser to print a translatable string t('SOLD'), so that everyone else (even anonymous) can see that this item is now sold.

In my corolla template.php I already have custom function that gives classes to different flags:

```
    function corolla_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $flag = flag_get_flag('sold'); // Machine name of your flag.
  if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($variables['node']->nid)) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-flag-sold';
  }
$flag = flag_get_flag('withdraw'); // Machine name of your flag.
  if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($variables['node']->nid)) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-flag-withdraw';   
  }
}
```

But I know that I need to modify this function and/or node--type.tpl.php to actually print a string t('SOLD').

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a new variable in your preprocess function and print it in your node--type.tpl.php as follows:

In template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {
    $flag = flag_get_flag('sold');
    if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($node->nid)) {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-flag-sold';
      $variables['flagged_text'] = t('Sold');
    }
  }
}
```

And in your node--YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php, put simply this snippet wherever you want to print the string:

```
<?php if ($flagged_text): ?>
  <?php print $flagged_text; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or the same code shorter:

```
<?php if ($flagged_text) print $flagged_text; ?>
```

But the first one is better for readability and follows the Drupal's coding standards for template files.

Comment: Thanks.I ended up doing it with just this inmy node--type.tpl

` <?php
$flag = flag_get_flag('sold');
if ($flag->is_flagged($node->nid)):
?>
<div class="sold"><img src="/css/images/sold3.png" /><div class="sold-text"><?php print t('SOLD') ?></div></div>
<?php endif; ?>  `

Comment: This would also work, but you should avoid putting complex logic in your template files. It is always better to prepare your variables for the template in the preprocess functions.